# Square integrability of functions

Tags: integration, analysis, functions

Suppose that for a function $f(x)\,\,, x\in\mathbb{R}$ holds
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}|f(x)|^{2} ~\mathrm{d}x<\infty
\end{align}
Does it also holds that 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}|f(x)|~\mathrm{d}x<\infty
~ ?
\end{align}
I am confused..

Comment: Hint: if $|f(x)|\ge 1$, then $|f(x)|\le|f(x)|^2$.

Comment: ok, now i see. Thank you ! But what happens if for example $f\in (0,1)$ ?

Comment: Note here that it is crucial that the domain of integration is finite.

Comment: If $A$ is the subset of $[0,T]$ where $|f|<1$, then $\int_A |f|<\infty$, since $A$ has finite measure. By the inequality above, $\int_{A^C\cap [0,T]}|f|<\infty$ also.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^T|f(x)|dx\leq \sqrt{T}(\int_0^T|f(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you @BigM. How do we know this estimate?

Comment: \begin{align} |f(x)|\leq |f(x)|^{2} \\ \int_{0}^{T}|f(x)|dx \leq \int_{0}^{T}|f(x)|^{2}dx<\infty   \end{align}

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.In fact the same is true in general measure space $(X,d\mu)$ as long as $\mu(X)<\infty.$